# does normality ascend along this finite flat morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian normal strict Henselian local ring with residue field of characteristic $p\ge 0$. Let $a\in A$ be a uniformizer in $A_P$ for some height 1 prime $P$, and $e$ be an integer coprime to $p$. Then $A[T]/(T^e-a)$ is finite free, hence flat over $A$. Must $A[T]/(T^e-a)$ be normal?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = F_2[x]_{(x)}$, $a = x^3$ and $e = 3$. Then 
$$
S = A[T]/(T^3-x^3) = F_2[x]_{(x)}[T]/ (T-x)(T^2 +xT+x^2). $$ 
Consider $S_m$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal $m = (x,T)S$. Since $S_m$ is not a domain, it is not normal, cf http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GV.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that the residue field is separably closed. I actually want to consider the case where $A$ is a normal strictly henselian local ring.

Comment: I don't think that will change anything. We can replace $F_2$ by its algebraic closure and localization by completion.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Though I've also edited the question to require that $a$ be a uniformizer for some dimension 1 localization. I think with that condition the statement is finally correct. (Sorry for the edits. This came up in my research)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes! To do this, we use Serre's criteria for normality, which is that a Noetherian ring $R$ is normal if and only if it satisfies:

1. It has property ($R_1$), which is to say that for every prime ideal $p$ of height $\le 1$, the local ring $R_p$ is regular.
2. It has property $(S_2$), which is to say that for every prime ideal $p$, the local ring $R_p$ has depth at least min$\{2,dim(R_p)\}$

For $(R_1)$, let $q$ be a prime ideal of $A[T]/(T^e-a)$ be of height $\le 1$, then let $p := q\cap A$. If $a\notin q$, then since $A$ is strictly Henselian, $T^e-a$ splits completely over $A$, and hence $A[T]/(T^e-a)\cong A^e$ which is normal since $A$ is. So we may assume that $a\in q$. Then there is a natural map 
$$A_p[T]/(T^e-a)\longrightarrow(A[T]/(T^e-a))_q$$
which realizes the target as a localization of the source. Since both rings are local of the same dimension, we find that this is an isomorphism. The source is a DVR by classical results, and hence the target is regular. This proves that $A[T]/(T^e-a)$ satisfies $(R_1)$.

For $(S_2)$, we use the result of http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0339 to reduce the problem to proving that the fibers of $A[T]/(T^e-a)$ over $A$ have $(S_2)$, but this is trivial since the fibers have the form $k[T]/(T^e)$ for some residue field $k$, which has dimension 0.